# PNG's don't load with allegro5, but BMP's do

Tags: c++, png, allegro5

I'm trying to learn how to use allegro5 so I installed it from source on their github and it was going fine until I tried to load an image. Here is my code that wasn't working.

```
#include<allegro5/allegro.h>
#include<allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
        al_init();
        al_init_image_addon();
        al_create_display(640,560);

        ALLEGRO_BITMAP * image = al_load_bitmap("pi.png");

        while(true){
                al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(100,0,0));
                if(image == NULL){
                        printf("Image didn't load properly\n");
                        return -1;
                }

                al_draw_bitmap(image, 0, 0, 0);
                al_flip_display();
        }
}
```

But after making a `pi.bmp` in the same directory and then changing the

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP * image = al_load_bitmap("pi.png");
```

to

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP * image = al_load_bitmap("pi.bmp");
```

It works as expected. I already have libpng16-16 and libpng-dev installed. I am compiling the file (main.cpp) with this command:

```
g++ main.cpp -I/usr/local/include/allegro5 -L/usr/local/lib -lallegro -lallegro_image -lpng
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: By not working I do mean that `image == NULL` is `true`. Also I just tried to do it on my laptop. I believe the problem must be somewhere with my installation. My desktop (the one that doesn't work) is running Ubuntu 18.10 (cosmic) and my laptop is running 18.04 (bionic) and works fine after adding the ppa and updating. It seems they only have pre-compiled binaries for bionic, which is what forced me to compile from source.

EDIT2: @rcorre's answer worked for me! Hopefully this will help someone else out in the future. When building you need to use the command `cmake -D WANT_IMAGE_PNG=1 ..` from the build directory.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099984/allegro-5-al-load-bitmap-not-working) is what you need?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "wasn't working" means? Is `image == NULL`, or does it just not display?

Comment: Did you build allegro with [`WANT_IMAGE_PNG`](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L134)? It should be on by default, but you should check. If your distro provides a pre-packaged allegro, you might try installing that for comparison.

Comment: @rcorre I'm not at home right now, but that sounds very promising. I didn't know about those WANTs when building. This is my first time building something like this from source so I've been trying to follow guides, but most seem to assume you can just link the ppa and be done.

Comment: Instead of editing your post you should answer your own question. ;)